# Как правильно регулировать уровень громкости?

Tags: c#, winapi, аудио

У меня получилось использовать только через winmm.dll, но в Windows 10 звук регулируется только у приложения, а мне нужно регулировать общий уровень громкости.

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hwo, uint dwVolume);
...
waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, NewVolumeAllChannels);
```

По описанию этой функции она принимает указатель на устройство вывода, но как его получить?

Также пробовал через NAudio, но он отказался работать на Windows 10. + перепробовал почти все способы на stackoverflow

Comment: В те варианты которые вы испробовали входит этот способ решения проблемы: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294292/changing-master-volume-level ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это легко сделать с помощью AudioEndpoint API. Работает начиная с Windows 7.

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
internal class MMDeviceEnumerator {
}

internal enum EDataFlow {
    eRender,
    eCapture,
    eAll,
    EDataFlow_enum_count
}

internal enum ERole {
    eConsole,
    eMultimedia,
    eCommunications,
    ERole_enum_count
}


[Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IMMDeviceEnumerator {
    int NotImpl1();

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow dataFlow, ERole role, out IMMDevice ppDevice);

    // the rest is not implemented
}

[Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IMMDevice {
    [PreserveSig]
    int Activate(ref Guid iid, int dwClsCtx, IntPtr pActivationParams, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppInterface);

    // the rest is not implemented
}

[Guid("657804FA-D6AD-4496-8A60-352752AF4F89"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback {
    int OnNotify(IntPtr pNotifyData);
};

[Guid("5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IAudioEndpointVolume {
    int RegisterControlChangeNotify(IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback pNotify);
    int UnregisterControlChangeNotify(IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback pNotify);
    int GetChannelCount(out int pnChannelCount);
    int SetMasterVolumeLevel(float fLevelDB, Guid pguidEventContext);
    int SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(float fLevel, Guid pguidEventContext);
    int GetMasterVolumeLevel(out float pfLevelDB);
    int GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(out float pfLevel);
    int SetChannelVolumeLevel(uint nChannel, float fLevelDB, Guid pguidEventContext);
    int SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(uint nChannel, float fLevel, Guid pguidEventContext);
    int GetChannelVolumeLevel(uint nChannel, out float pfLevelDB);
    int GetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(uint nChannel, out float pfLevel);
    int SetMute([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] Boolean bMute, Guid pguidEventContext);
    int GetMute(out bool pbMute);
    int GetVolumeStepInfo(out uint pnStep, out uint pnStepCount);
    int VolumeStepUp(Guid pguidEventContext);
    int VolumeStepDown(Guid pguidEventContext);
    int QueryHardwareSupport(out uint pdwHardwareSupportMask);
    int GetVolumeRange(out float pflVolumeMindB, out float pflVolumeMaxdB, out float pflVolumeIncrementdB);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
    IMMDevice speakers = null;
    IAudioEndpointVolume vol = null;
    try
    {
        deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);
        Guid IID_IAudioEndpointVolume = typeof(IAudioEndpointVolume).GUID;
        object o;
        speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioEndpointVolume, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o);
        vol = (IAudioEndpointVolume)o;
        vol.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(0.7f, Guid.Empty);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    if (vol != null)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(vol);
    }
    if (speakers != null)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
    }

    if (deviceEnumerator != null)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
    }
}
```

Comment: а как можно отключить звук только в своем приложении?

Comment: @Lightness http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480724/Как-отключить-звук-в-своем-приложении-в-windows/480725#480725