# Как отключить звук в своем приложении в Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi

В Windows 7 можно управлять громкостью как всей системы в целом, так и каждого процесса в отдельности. Как можно программным способом отключить звук для текущего процесса?

Answer (score 5):

Это легко можно сделать с помощью [AudioEndpoint API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd370832(v=vs.85).aspx). Работает, начиная с Windows 7. [Здесь можно прочесть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd370832(v=vs.85).aspx), что такое Audio Endpoint Devices.

По правде говоря, приложение может иметь не только одну аудио-сессию. Сессии идентифицируются по GUID. Но для простоты положим, что сессия только одна, и передадим `GUID_NULL`.

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IAudioSessionManager2, __uuidof(IAudioSessionManager2));

bool MuteCurrentProcess() {
    IAudioSessionManager2Ptr mgr;
    CreateSessionManager(&mgr);
    ISimpleAudioVolumePtr volume;
    if (SUCCEEDED(mgr->GetSimpleAudioVolume(&GUID_NULL, false, &volume))) {
        ISimpleAudioVolumePtr vol;
        volume->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), (void**)&vol);

        if (SUCCEEDED(volume->SetMute(TRUE, 0))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: В предпоследней строке видимо должно быть `return false;` Это Ваш [код](http://pastebin.com/SAs4yvix) или неудачная копипаста?

Comment: Да, это мой код, но он не используется мной ни в одном проекте. Спасибо, что заметили ошибку.